# VS confusing option: converting web-application to web-application

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, web-applications

Could anyone explain, why is there an option to convert an Asp.Net **Web-application**
(both Web Forms and MVC) to convert to a **Web-application.**

This might be something of a help for web-site template but why for Web-application ? Is this

[alt text http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/372/41728917.jpg](http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/372/41728917.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: In a web application you can actually delete your designer-generated files.  Choosing this option will then re-create/generate the files.  I've only used it for debugging issues with the aspx files which cause the designer file not to be generated on changes.  You can also pull in aspx files from other sites without designer files.  I can't say that fully explains why the option remains, but it can come in handy sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question should help you out:

[Creating a new website on IIS: Application vs. Virtual Directory. Whats the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002981/creating-a-new-website-on-iis-application-vs-virtual-directory-whats-the-diffe)

> "There are a few differences, here are
>   the biggest:
>
> In IIS 6 and up, you can assign a Web Application a certain "protection"
>   level. (e.g. protection levels,
>   application pools, etc). You can't do
>   this with Virtual Directories. If you
>   are working with ASP.NET, the search
>   for the master "Web.config" file for
>   your application stops at your
>   application level. For a working
>   directory it will actually check your
>   parent hierarchy for settings as well.
>   These are the two biggest differences
>   in my opinion, although there are
>   other small ones as well."
>   - [mjmarsh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29798/mjmarsh)

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't answer the original question, does it? The question was "Why is this option there when the project already is a web application?"