# SharePoint Virtual Directories Sitemap

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sitemap

I have created and asp.net web site utilizing a web.sitemap file to help with navigation.  The site needs to be deployed within a virtual directory inside of our SharePoint intranet site.  The problem that I am running in to is that when I request the SiteMap.CurrentNode property, it is returning information from SharePoint's sitemap.  Specifically, when i try to get my sitemap's title or description, I am getting information from SharePoint. I have tried re-naming my sitemap and declaring a new Sitemap provider within the web.config. After creating the new sitemap provider and requesting the SiteMap.currentNode, I receive an error message saying that it can't find the web.sitemap file.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the problem...It turns out that when I declared the new site map provider within the web.config, I didn't set the defaultProvider value.  Once the default provider was set to the new provider's name, everything worked as expected.

```
<siteMap enabled="true" defaultProvider="CPSiteMap">
  <providers>
    <add name="CPSiteMap" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="AccountMaintenance.sitemap" />
  </providers>
</siteMap>
```

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to set the virtual directory as an Application within IIS - doing this will:

- reset the "base" directory of your application to the root of the virtual directory, so that relative paths in your web.config point to the correct location,  and
- cause the website to ignore any settings defined any Sharepoint web.config files defined in parent folders, and
- should also make your sitemap file the default (because it won't look at any web.config or sitemaps in parent directories).

There [are other differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002981/creating-a-new-website-on-iis-application-vs-virtual-directory-whats-the-diffe), but these two seem to be the cause of the problems you've outlined.