# Correct IIS 7.5 physical path

Tags: iis

In IIS 7.5 I have a site called `App` with one application `App` and one Virtual Directory `Vir`.

```
c:\Website\App
c:\Website\Vir
```

Let's say my starting page is as follows:

```
c:\Website\App\Default.asp
```

Is the correct physical path for the site?

```
c:\Website
```

or is it

```
c:\Website\App
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the path you have defined for virtual directory of the site.

1. If you have create this page is app(**c:\Website\site**) or site(**c:\Website\App**) then it refers to its virtual directory physical path.
2. If you have created this page in specific virtual directory(**c:\Website\Vir**) then it refers to its physical path.

Actually you need to understand the difference  **site vs application vs virtual directory** in IIS. you can refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500326/whats-the-difference-between-web-app-and-virtual-folder-in-the-context-of-iis-7)