# Deploy asp.net mvc chidren project in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

Currently we encounter a concern to deploy this application with children applications on IIS.
We would like each module is deployed as a virtual directory of the master application and not application in IIS.
But now when trying to access the various applications areas child , he always spring a 404 error .
What would be the proper way to operate its different module from virtual directories of the master application ?

We use VS2013 / Framework 4.5 / IIS 7.5.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a big difference between an Application and a virtual directory:
[What's the difference between Web App and Virtual Folder in the context of IIS 7.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500326/whats-the-difference-between-web-app-and-virtual-folder-in-the-context-of-iis-7)

Check in IIS if your virtual directory is an Application, and change according to your wishes

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't want my child projects are applications because they are parts of the parent application. That is why I want to use only virtual directories. But I can not access the pages of these children applications. ( error 404 )

Comment: For IIS/ASP.NET there is no difference between a folder and a virtual directory. For Applications there is a big difference, is the application removed from the virtual directory?

Comment: Yes , the virtual directory points directly to the physical directory of the child project . There is no application in this virtual directory

Comment: There is no application in this virtual directory <-- This is your problem. A "child project" must be configured as an application. Otherwise it must be part of the original project (compiled into the same DLL). But frankly, unless it is absolutely necessary, it is much simpler just to put everything into a single project.

Comment: And a "child" application doesn't exist in IIS/ASP.NET. Every application has it's own settings/memory/app pool. An Application can live in a subfolder of another application, but there is no link between them

Comment: Ok, thank you for that. I will continue to use a single project for the entire application .