# What is the difference between creating a virtual directory, and publishing an application in IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I understand that we can host an application in IIS using a virtual directory.And also we can host an application in IIS by using the publishing option in vs. Is there any difference between using a virtual directory and using the publishing option?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Try to isolate the newly hosted app so that crash in one doesn't affect another, try to recycle just one of those apps without affecting others. Try to host 32 bit and 64 bit apps. Try to keep apps isolated. (Hint: Application Pool)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between Web App and Virtual Folder in the context of IIS 7.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500326/whats-the-difference-between-web-app-and-virtual-folder-in-the-context-of-iis-7)

Answer (score 0):

A virtual directory is more a like a windows shortcut to the real directory of the main app. Just like you can have many shortcuts with different names, same goes for virtual directories more like an abstraction layer..

Comment: then what is publishing

Comment: Simply means copying your files to the app directory on iis/xamp or other host.

Comment: ok..so run the application using virtual directory means executing the application by going through the system local directory and publishing means run the application by copying the files from system local directory to iis and run the application from iis

Comment: I think you go it mixed up. First you create a directory inside `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` folder with whatever name you want to use, then create a virtual directory in IIS (i assume you already have iis running), after that simply copy your local files the folder/directory you created in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot' , launch your browser, use localhost/nameOfSubDirectory to view/run your application

Comment: Ok Thankyou Donnie